# Rectangle is not shown in QML

Tags: qt, qml

In this `QML` example the `Rectangle` is NOT shown. The label *Usuarios* does appear, but the rectangle itself does not. Very weird behavior , can you tell why is that? You can test this example with `qmlscene`.

Example code:

Main file:

```
$ cat UsersGroups.qml 
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    header: TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Users")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Groups")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Schedules")
        }
    }
    StackLayout {
        width: parent.width
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        Users {
            id: users
        }
        Groups {
            id: groups
        }
        Schedules {
            id: schedules
        }
    }
}
```

**Secondary files**

Users file:

```
$ cat Users.qml 
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "blue"
        border.color: "red"
        border.width: 5
        Label {
            text: "Usuarios"
        }
    }
}
```

Groups file:

```
$ cat Groups.qml 
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    Label {
        text: "Grupos"
    }
}
```

Schedules file:

```
$ cat Schedules.qml 
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0


Item {
    Label {
        text: "Schedules"
    }
}
```

Will appreciate any pointers on solving this issue.

Comment: Height of `StackLayout` is missing so the height of the `Rectangle` is 0 which is not visible. Add `height: parent.height` to `StackLayout` can solve the problem.

Comment: @mcchu. you are right. Added height and it worked. Why does Label works then ? But Rectangle does not. Rectangle should be enclosing the Label. Bug in QT?

Comment: Because the Rectangle does not [clip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop) by default. If you add `clip:true` to that Rectangle (or it's parent Item), then the Label is not shown, too.

Comment: @mcchu, got it all now, thank you very much. you may answer the question , I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height of `StackLayout` is missing so the default height of the `Rectangle` is 0 which is not visible. Set height to `StackLayout` can solve the problem:

```
StackLayout {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    //...
}
```